# Unable to add the SKNode image buttons inside a scrollable layout in Swift spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I'm totally new to swift and spritekit and having trouble with setting the buttons like the sample below inside a scrollable view or layout (if there is such a thing in spritekit). I have only experience in Android development and I want to know if there is a way to add the SKNode buttons inside a scrollable like android's ScrollView? I want to add the SKNodes vertically in a scrollable. For example, how to set the SKLabels or SKNode images into a Scollable ? Sorry for my poor English.

```
scoreLabel.fontSize = 15
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5  , y: (self.size.height * 0.5) + 100)
scoreLabel.zPosition = 2
scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

//titleLabel.color = UIColor.blackColor()

self.addChild(scoreLabel)        

startLabel.name = "hard"
startLabel.text = "Hard"

startLabel.fontSize = 30
startLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: 300)
startLabel.zPosition = 2
startLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.addChild(startLabel)

startLabel2.name = "previousButton"
startLabel2.text = "Normal"

startLabel2.fontSize = 30
startLabel2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: 250)
startLabel2.zPosition = 2
startLabel2.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.addChild(startLabel2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily mixup sprite kit and uikit for your situation UICollectionView is best add UICollectionView as a subview and pass data to that UICollectionView for example images and text remember UICollectionView is a part of uikit so SKNode can't be added to UICollectionView but you can add any view as a subview to your sprite kit SKScene for more information read

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the link ! But the link is not working. Do you think there is some other good tutorial or sample out there ? I've been googling for a while but wasn't able to find an easy to learn material for a noob like me.

Comment: sorry dude for my mistake i correct the link for you first link and about uikit and second link contain a uicollectionview (scrollview in android) with sample code by apple

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!